# Why were these plagiarism flags declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, specific-answer, plagiarism

First off, let me preface this by asking all of you to **not go mob downvoting** this user's content on the main site.

I flagged two answers from a user as plagiarizing content from other answers, but the flags were recently declined. For one of the answers, I can sort of understand why, but I don't understand why the other one was declined:

[image]

### Answer 1

This is one of the answers that I flagged:

> > Oracle does not support the LIMIT or OFFSET keywords. If you want to
> >     retrieve rows N through M of a result set
>
> you need something like
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM
> (
>  select *,rank() over (order by some_column) rnk from table_name 
> ) AS T
> WHERE rnk BETWEEN <<lower limit>> AND <<upper limit>>
> Order By something Desc
> ```
>
> Take a look at [**here**](http://www.codespaces.com/blog/2011/02/24/oracle-limiting-the-number-of-records-like-top-n-limit/) `<==` DEAD LINK to CodeSpaces.com

I flagged it as plagiarizing this answer:

> Prior to 12.1, Oracle does not support the `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`
>   keywords.  If you want to retrieve rows N through M of a result set,
>   you'd need something like
>
> ```
> SELECT a.*
>   FROM (SELECT b.*,
>                rownum b_rownum
>           FROM (SELECT c.*
>                   FROM some_table c
>                  ORDER BY some_column) b
>          WHERE rownum <= <<upper limit>>) a
>  WHERE b_rownum >= <<lower limit>>
> ```
>
> or using analytic functions
>
> ```
> SELECT a.*
>   FROM (SELECT b.*,
>                rank() over (order by some_column) rnk
>           FROM some_table)
>  WHERE rnk BETWEEN <<lower limit>> AND <<upper limit>>
>  ORDER BY some_column
> ```

Notice that both answers have the same intro, and the the 2nd code block in the original answer matches the code block in the plagiarized one, including the distinctive line

```
WHERE rnk BETWEEN <<lower limit>> AND <<upper limit>>
```

Also note that the plagiarized answer **does not cite** the original, it's a dead link to CodeSpaces.com. Maybe that site used to be a Stack Overflow scraper that went offline? Is that why my flag was declined for that answer?

### Answer 2

The suspect answer:

> You should use the `N'` prefix to indicate that you're searching for a
>   Unicode string:
>
> ```
> select * from Cars where Cars.PlateNumber =N'٧٦٣طجم'
> ```
>
> [**Creating Unicode-compliant SQL Queries**](http://www.scribesoft.com/helplibrary/prod/en/Subsystems/Insight/configsource/sqlqueries/creating_a_sql_query_with_unicode_data.htm)

The answer that I identified as the original:

> You should use the `N'` prefix to indicate that you're searching for a
>   Unicode string:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM dbo.tblArticle WHERE name LIKE N'%......%'
> ```
>
> Otherwise, you're converting your search string back to non-Unicode
>   and then searching....

Note that the question that the suspected plagiarized answer is on was marked as a duplicate of the question that the original answer is on.

Comment: Not to say your flags should have been declined, but in both cases I see a partial attempt at providing attribution, by linking to the original content. In both cases you could have fixed this with a little editing; putting in the correct link, turning text into a blockquote. Did you leave comments asking the OP to improve their attribution skills? The help center offers links to Meta.SE posts about how to do this too.

Comment: The Internet Archive still has a link to the codespaces.com blog post: http://web.archive.org/web/20130927072334/http://www.codespaces.com/blog/2011/02/24/oracle-limiting-the-number-of-records-like-top-n-limit I see no hint of the original plagiarised answer, so that post is not attributing anything there.

Comment: In cases such as these I link to the [help center post on attribution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), ask the OP to attribute their post to the original author (linking it) and educate them about the issue. I then hunt for more such cases. I also flag, providing as much evidence as I can; I do pre-digest this as much as possible (explain in *detail* what part is copied if it is not wholesale). These copies were not as cut and dry so the moderator probably missed it.

Comment: That said, the account in question has been suspended for plagiarism, so clearly you were on to something here. :-)

Comment: Now I know why you went direct :) Are you using SEDE to find duplicate content?

Comment: A moderator recently told me that moderators are not here to enforce plagiarism rules even when notified of them and the content was the entire external article stolen. I believe Stack Exchange deal with plagiarism only on external notice.

Comment: @usr what if someone plagiarizes *another user's* content from the [se] network though?...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I declined those flags, mostly because the parts that were copied seemed minimal.

On the first answer:

> Oracle does not support the LIMIT or OFFSET keywords. If you want to retrieve rows N through M of a result set

I can't think of many ways to rephrase this, and it looks like copy that two people might have both come up with after reading common documentation. When I looked at the code from the two answers, I thought they were different enough that it wasn't worth flagging as plagiarism.

Second answer:

> You should use the N' prefix to indicate that you're searching for a Unicode string

This also looks like a common phrase that could have easily come out of reading the documentation.  The code snippets are short, and each was customized to answer their respective questions, so those also could have been arrived at independently.

I didn't think a large enough percentage of either answer was copied to justify a plagiarism flag, but looking at them side-by-side, I think it's pretty clear that the user is borrowing from other answers. If I had noticed that they were from the same user I probably would have handled the flags differently.

---

On a related note, the flagging you've been doing around plagiarism lately has been fantastic! Other people are starting to use your queries, and we're clearing a lot of plagiarized posts. Thank you, and please keep it up!

Comment: You just revealed Cupcake's shortcake and waffles secret! :(

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I know waffles and Cupcake, but now you're telling me there's a shortcake running around? This is the weirdest gang...

Comment: I have linked the shortcake in a deleted comment for you, so that others can't see it. Cupcake is doing a great job with his desserts. I feel desserts would soon be banned in some parts of the world, all thanks to Cupcake.

Comment: +1 for the appreciation given in last part of your answer. Mods should _more often_ appreciate what users are doing to keep this place clean.

Comment: @Omar shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @Cupcake does my previous comment neglect mods support and effort? Usually, appreciation/gratitude given from persons with higher authority to others with less authority is sincere, constructive and motivative. The other way around _might_ be fake (IMHO). Appreciation is the best motivation tool. Read more about [Maslow pyramid](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow's_hierarchy_of_needs)